# What is difference between White Color set from storyboard and UIColor.whiteColor()?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

For a `UIButton`, I have set its background color as `White Color` in storyboard. I want to toggle the properties of the button depending on the current `backgroundColor` of my button.

```
func toggleButton(button: UIButton) {
     if button.backgroundColor == UIColor.whiteColor() {
          button.backgroundColor = UIColor.myDesiredColor()
          button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     }else {
          button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          button.tintColor = UIColor.myDesiredColor()
     }
}
```

The check for `button.backgroundColor == UIColor.whiteColor()` never returns `true` and after debugging, I found out that value of `White Color` set from `Storyboard` is different from value of `UIColor.whiteColor()`.

**Debugging result:**
Storyboard White Color - `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1`
`UIColor.whiteColor()` - `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1`

I have found out workaround for my code to work as expected.

**My real confusion are:**

- What is difference between these two values?
- Why does Xcode have two different value of same color in storyboard and code?
- How do these two different white colors differ from each other?

Comment: @downVoter, read full question rather than just title.

Comment: Can you do a print(button.backgrondColor)? Maybe even as rgb values.

Comment: I wrote an obj-c category to compare UIColors even across color spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variations in your results differ not so much because of the color used (after all they are both white), but rather in the resulting **colorspace** that is used: (`RGB` and the other is `Device`)

**Device Color**

Device colors are meant to be true representations of colors as perceived by the human eye. A device-independent color space starts with a white reference point, a black reference point, and gamma values for a particular device. iOS Quartz takes that information to convert colors of a source color space into the color space of the output device. Device color is also the standard defined by the International Color Consortium.

> ICC profiles define the gamut of colors supported by a device along
>   with other device characteristics so that this information can be used
>   to accurately transform the color space of one device to the color
>   space of another.

**RGB**

RGB is a three-dimensional color space are made up of varying values of red, green, and blue intensities that make up a given color. It's the most commonly used color space in computer graphics, because it's directly supported by most every color display that's around today. RGB color spaces are device dependent and additive.

> Signals are transmitted to the elements on the face of the monitor,
>   causing them to glow at various intensities of red, green, and blue
>   (the combination of which makes up the required hue, saturation, and
>   brightness of the desired colors)

↳ [iOS: Color and Color Spaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_color/dq_color.html)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of visible color, there is no difference. Both are regular white.

But technically, as you've debugged, they are two different objects which differs by the color space they use. One is created with RGB color space with all channels set to their maximum values. And the other is created with White color space (grayscale) with maximum white. On both spaces last value is the alpha value.

Below white color should satisfy your condition since it's using RGB color space.

```
UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

> Why does Xcode have two different value of same color in storyboard
>   and code?

That's really not easy to answer. From storyboard, even if you use the grayscale slider to create white. It converts it to built in storyboard white which is RGB. That's just the way it is I guess.

Comment: Your answer did help to understand the difference between the two. But, one thing that is still confusing is that both being white colors and both being object of same class `UIColor`, both should have same value, right? But still, the `==` operator (which compares value) returns `false` when applied to `storyboard white` and `UIColor.whiteColor()`. This concludes that even though these both object represent same color, they still have different values, which is little weird.

Comment: No definitely they shouldn't have same values. By saying value don't let the visible color confuse you. On run time they both rendered  as the white we all know. But on code level their values are based on the color space they use.